# How to add native android project to react native?

Tags: android, react-native

I've been searching on how to make a bridge between React Native and Android Native code for a while, but I still don't quite get it.
I also read the facebook docs but I don't quite understand it.I have a android project and I want to integrate it into react native project with native UI.
    Any kind of help will be appreciated !!

Comment: What have you tried? Which bits don't you understand?

Comment: If I am using a native functionality I can use it like the android toast example given in facebook docs..but If I want to use the whole android project I didn't find any resource material for it..

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that is possible. If I understand correct you want to use existing android project and mix it with react native to make cross-platform. You simply can't do that. All of the work has to be done from scratch. A new react native project has to be created. The reason is quite simple android native's code cannot be converted or used in react native. I have come across many people asking the same thing and I always suggest that read the docs very carefully. [Check this](https://medium.com/we-talk-it/react-native-what-it-is-and-how-it-works-e2182d008f5e)

Comment: No you cannot use XML. React-Native uses its own css like styling which is basically javascript. you can read more about that in [link](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/style)